# ByteBuddy how to have some code executed at class load time

Tags: byte-buddy

I am using bytebuddy to dynamically create Classes, Enums and Interfaces and I want to have some code executed at class load time to initialize some of the static fields which is normaly done in `<clinit>`. what are the APIs in bytebuddy that I can use to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instrument the initializer via:

```
builder.invokeable(isTypeInitalizer()).intercept(...)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. at first it did not worked for me but when I marked the interceptor class as public it was working.